# import csv to redis with hash datatype

Tags: csv, ubuntu, awk, redis

```
awk -F, 'NR > 0{print "SET", "\"calc_"NR"\"", "\""$0"\"" }' files/calc.csv | unix2dos | redis-cli --pipe
```

I use the above command to import a csv file into redis database with string datatype.Something like,

```
set cal_1 product,cost,quantity
set cal_2 t1,100,5
```

How do I import as hash datatype with field name as rowcount , key as column header, value as column value in awk.

```
HMSET calc:1 product "t1" cost 100 quantity 5
HMSET calc:2 product "t2" cost 500 quantity 4
```

Input file Example:

```
product    cost    quantity
 t1         100      5
 t2         500      4
 t3         600      9
```

Can I get this result from awk
for each row present in csv file,

HMSET calc_'row no' 1st row 1st column value  current row 1st column value  1st row 2nd column value  current row 2nd column value 1st row 3rd column value urrent row 3rd column value

so for the above example,

```
HMSET calc_1 product t1 cost 100 quantity 5
HMSET calc_2 product t2 cost 500 quantity 4
HMSET calc_3 product t3 cost 600 quantity 9
```

for all the rows dynamically?

Comment: I would be happy to help you but could you just clarify your input and expected output and I will make it for you ;-)

Comment: @Allan I have added sample input and output please check now. TIA

Comment: And I dont want to run a for loop to fetch the data as it will be vast

Comment: have you checked my answer hereunder? if you need more explanation about awk let me know

Comment: @Allan I have edited my question now with detailed awk requirement can you check please

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{if(NR==1){col1=$1; col2=$2; col3=$3}else{product[NR]=$1;cost[NR]=$2;quantity[NR]=$3;tmp=NR}}END{printf "[("col1","col2","col3"),"; for(i=2; i<=tmp;i++){printf "("product[i]","cost[i]","quantity[i]")";}print "]";}' input_file.txt
```

on your input file:

```
product    cost    quantity
 t1         100      5
 t2         500      4
 t3         600      9
```

it gives the following output:

```
[(product,cost,quantity),(t1,100,5)(t2,500,4)(t3,600,9)]
```

[image]

**awk commands:**

```
# gawk profile, created Fri Dec 29 15:12:39 2017

# Rule(s)

{
        if (NR == 1) { # 1
                col1 = $1
                col2 = $2
                col3 = $3
        } else {
                product[NR] = $1
                cost[NR] = $2
                quantity[NR] = $3
                tmp = NR
        }
}

# END rule(s)

END {
        printf "[(" col1 "," col2 "," col3 "),"
        for (i = 2; i <= tmp; i++) {
                printf "(" product[i] "," cost[i] "," quantity[i] ")"
        }
        print "]"
}
```

Comment: No I guess the question is not clear. I want to import the file into redis database and get the expected output by fetching from redis. Not directly into a csv.

Comment: And that was just a example input i will not be knowing the exact column names or count

Comment: I see... I am not a `redis` expert at all sorry but if you need help about `awk` I can help you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help :) now I will post if required again.